# IAM AWS S3 to restrict to a specific sub-folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS S3 component to store files.

I have a bucket called "**mybucket**" and with the following folders :

```
+---Mybucket
\---toto1
\---toto2
+---toto3
|   \--- subfolder
|       \---subsubfolder
\---toto4
```

I have AWS console users that need only need to access "toto3" folder.

I tried to restrict the access to this folder, but the user must have the right to list the root of bucket. If I put additional rights to acces the root folder, users can browser "toto1" and "toto2" folders and I don't want.

I want to configure something like that:

- Authorize to list all buckets of my S3 account (listAllBuckets policy)
- Autorize to list the root of the bucket (it's OK for me if the user see the directories names)
- Deny access for all prefix bucket different from "toto3"
- Autorize every actions for the user in toto3 folder
- I don't want to write an inclusive rules

I tried this IAM policy without any success :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/toto3/*"]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1457617383000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1457617230000",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": ["s3:*"],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "toto3*"
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a policy that will work for you:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/toto3/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1457617230000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "toto3/"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Details:

- `ListAllMyBuckets` is required by the Console. It shows a list of all buckets.
- Any action permitted within the `toto3/` path.
- `ListBucket` (retrieve objects list) permitted in the root of the bucket and in the `toto3/` path.

I successfully tested this solution.

AWS Documentation Reference: [Allow Users to Access a Personal "Home Directory" in Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-s3-home-directory)

Comment: Also see this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

Comment: So `"s3:prefix": [ "" ] allows `ListBucket` only at bucket's root level, i.e. listing folder names but not their contents expect the path starting with `toto3/`? Is that correct?

Comment: @W.M. no this is not correct, if you use ls --recursive it will give you the entire list of files in the bucket, this is obviously not the wanted isolation behavior

Answer (score 2):

I edit your code to have the following and it works ! THanks !!

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/toto3/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "toto3/",
                        "toto3*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This lets you list all the files in the entire bucket, is this the wanted behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I need to grant an external vendor access only to a subfolder under a folder, that was under a bucket (!!!). Something like this:

bucket/folder/subfolder

Here's how I accomplished it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ]
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "bucket/folder/subfolder/*",
                        "bucket/folder/subfolder/",
                        "bucket/folder/subfolder",
                        "folder/subfolder/*",
                        "folder/subfolder/",
                        "folder/subfolder",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You do not need to have the bucket in the condition's prefix.

Answer (score -2):

Is it possible to limit the below rule but give specific folder access? I don't want the user see the directory names/folder names with-in the specific bucket.

Autorize to list the root of the bucket (it's OK for me if the user see the directories names)

Comment: Please ask a separate question